# JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type "" from Array value

Tags: java, json, postgresql, spring-boot

I have an object
`Event(Long id,String name, LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime stop, Desk desk(Long id, String name)`
And i want to save at the database with a Create method :

```
@PostMapping("/flexoffice/events/create")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
public Event create(@RequestBody Event newEvent){
    // It checks if the event is available, if the office is not taken during the time interval. If it is not, it throws an exception.
    if (eventRepository.checkIfAvailable(newEvent.getDesk().getId(), newEvent.getStart(),newEvent.getStop()) == true) {

        throw new ResponseStatusException(HttpStatus.CONFLICT,"créneau en conflit avec un autre");
    }
    return this.eventRepository.save(newEvent);

}
```

When i try to execute the postmapping on Postman with a RequestBody in Json format :

```
[{
"name": "Michellllllllllll",
"start": "2021-01-01T00:01:00",
"stop": "2021-03-06T00:01:00",
"desk": {
  "name": "B-1",
  "id": 9
}}]
```

It return :

```
 Hibernate: select desk0_.Id as id1_1_0_, desk0_.board_id as board_id3_1_0_, desk0_.name as name2_1_0_, board1_.id as id1_0_1_, board1_.name as name2_0_1_ from desk desk0_ left outer join board board1_ on desk0_.board_id=board1_.id where desk0_.Id=?
2022-10-14 10:37:04.814 
 WARN 19272 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `org.flexoffice.application.entity.Event` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `org.flexoffice.application.entity.Event` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)<EOL> at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]]
```

I already try to use an empty class, catch all request body in string and format then, etc. and nothing change. help me please !

Comment: What happens if you remove the square brackets from the json file?

Comment: it's return this in console : `Hibernate: select case when count(*)>0 then false else true end as col_0_0_ from event event0_ where desk_id=? and (event0_.start>=? or event0_.stop>=?) and (event0_.start<=? or event0_.stop<=?)` (from my method checkIfAvailable())

Comment: and if i try to bypass checkIfAvailable : `2022-10-14 14:01:26.826 ERROR 18640 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "hibernate_sequence" does not exist
`

Answer (score 1):

Try this JSON as request body:

```
{
   "name":"Michellllllllllll",
   "start":"2021-01-01T00:01:00",
   "stop":"2021-03-06T00:01:00",
   "desk":{
      "name":"B-1",
      "id":9
   }
}
```

and It is not recommended to use entities as DTO (Data Transfer Object) between client and server.

You can consume new event details by `EventDto(String name, Date start, Date stop, Long deskId)` and then map it to EventEntity

Comment: same error code. I don’t know how I can have this error knowing that I take the same structure and the same input and output as another project where it worked perfectly.

Comment: can you share code repository

Comment: `
@Repository
public interface EventRepository  extends JpaRepository<Event,Long> {`

`    @Query("select case when count(*) > 0 then false else true end as available " +
            "from Event where desk_id =:desk_id and not ((start < :start and stop < :start ) " +
            "or(start > :stop and stop > :stop) )")

    public Boolean checkIfAvailable(@Param("desk_id") Long desk, @Param("start") LocalDateTime start, @Param("stop")  LocalDateTime stop);


`

Comment: This is HQL version:  @Query("SELECT COUNT(t) > 0 FROM Event t WHERE t.desk.id=:deskId AND NOT ((t.start < :start AND t.stop < :start ) OR (t.start > :stop AND t.stop > :stop))")
    boolean checkIfAvailable(Long deskId, LocalDateTime start, LocalDateTime stop);

Comment: This is your version with native query:   @Query(value = "select case when count(*) > 0 then false else true end as available from Event where desk_id =:desk_id and not ((start < :start and stop < :start ) or (start > :stop and stop > :stop) )", nativeQuery = true) 
public Boolean checkIfAvailable(@Param("desk_id") Long desk, @Param("start") LocalDateTime start, @Param("stop") LocalDateTime stop);